# PHP MySQL Codeigniter update uploaded array files

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I try to update my uploaded file, but until right now

> i get eror message "erorr number 1064".

Here my models

```
public function update_tool_document($context, $data ){
    $header = "";

    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
        $header .= ", doc_title_" . $i. " = '" . $data['doc']['title'][$i-1] . "'";
        $header .= ", doc_display_" . $i. " = '" . $data['doc']['show'][$i-1] . "'";

        $header .=", link_to_doc_file_" . $i. " = '".(($data['doc']['link'][$i-1] != "")?"'".$data['doc']['link'][$i-1]."'":"link_to_doc_file_".$i)."'";        
    }


    $query = "UPDATE ms_tool_type_document SET $header
    WHERE tool_code = '".$data['tool_code']."'";

    $table = $context->db->query($query);

    return $table;
}
```

whats wrong with the link_to_doc_file. The erorr result is like this :
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' doc_title_1 = 'Tesst', doc_display_1 = '', link_to_doc_file_1 = ''material/tuto' at line 1

```
UPDATE ms_tool_type_document SET , doc_title_1 = 'Tesst', doc_display_1 = '', link_to_doc_file_1 = ''material/tutorial-prestashop.pdf'', doc_title_2 = 'hahaha', doc_display_2 = '', link_to_doc_file_2 = ''material/201512101342_INVOICE-NKOPP.pdf'', doc_title_3 = '', doc_display_3 = '', link_to_doc_file_3 = 'link_to_doc_file_3', doc_title_4 = '', doc_display_4 = '', link_to_doc_file_4 = 'link_to_doc_file_4', doc_title_5 = '', doc_display_5 = '', link_to_doc_file_5 = 'link_to_doc_file_5', doc_title_6 = '', doc_display_6 = '', link_to_doc_file_6 = 'link_to_doc_file_6', doc_title_7 = '', doc_display_7 = '', link_to_doc_file_7 = 'link_to_doc_file_7', doc_title_8 = '', doc_display_8 = '', link_to_doc_file_8 = 'link_to_doc_file_8', doc_title_9 = '', doc_display_9 = '', link_to_doc_file_9 = 'link_to_doc_file_9', doc_title_10 = '', doc_display_10 = '', link_to_doc_file_10 = 'link_to_doc_file_10' WHERE tool_code = 'T00005'
```

> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\lalalala\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> ```
> Line Number: 331
> ```

Comment: Missing column name here `SET $header...`

Comment: the column i try update uploaded file is link_to_doc_file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in query:

```
$query = "UPDATE ms_tool_type_document SET '".$header."'
WHERE tool_code = '".$data['tool_code']."'";
```

hope this will work!

Comment: Where is the column name to set header!!

Comment: by the way thanks but it not work, the problem issue is in here : $header .=", link_to_doc_file_" . $i. " = '".(($data['doc']['link'][$i-1] != "")?"'".$data['doc']['link'][$i-1]."'":"link_to_doc_file_".$i)."'";

Answer (score 1):

You ca write your update query using active record as

```
$this->db->set('link_to_doc_file',$header);
$this->db->where('tool_code',$data['tool_code']);
$this->db->update('ms_tool_type_document');
```

Make sure you column set to `text` to accept such a huge string